# Laravel 4: Route to Resourceful Method in Form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a form to update a Resource, I generate all the boilerplate with artisan, and now I can't figure out how to specify the route to the `update()`method of the controller in the form (I'm not using blade), and pass the id to the function. I know the route have be in the form (for example)  `/user/8/update`. I've tried with the helpers, but the route they create don't point to the update method.

Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/user/8/edit` ? http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: No, I'm talking about the route in the action of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figure it out how to do it by using Laravel's Forms:

```
Form::open(array('action' => array('UserController@update', $user->id), 'method' => 'put', ));
```